# Binding a textbox to a datagridviewtextboxcolumn?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Is it possible, to bind (or similar) a standard textbox to display the contents (dynamically) of the selected cell within a datagridview textboxcolumn?

My goal is that when a cell within this column has it's value altered, the `textbox.text` is also changed, and when the user selects a cell then types something in this separate textbox the value is updating the datagridview textboxcolumns value on the fly.

Comment: Is this DataGridView has bounded or unbounded columns?

Comment: it has databound columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may bind common dataSource to both TextBox and DataGridView.

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Item { get; set; }
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>()
      {
       new Foo() { Item="1" },
       new Foo() { Item="2" }
   };

  dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
  textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", list, "Item");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You provide an example of DataBinding to a List object, and the question was for a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the idea from "adatapost" to a DataGridView in C#:

```
        TextBox txt = this.txtBox1;
        DataGridView dgv = this.datagridview1;
        txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", dgv.DataSource, "FieldName");
        dgv = null;
        txt = null;
```

It might not be necessary to declare separate variables to hold your TextBox and DataGridView while you create the Binding. I just show these for clarity, in fact, this would be sufficient:

```
this.txtBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.datagridview1.DataSource, "FieldName"
```

To clarify, "Text" means output the value back to the "Text" property of the TextBox, and "FieldName" should be replaced with whatever the column is in your DataGridView that you want to bind to.

Note - make sure that you have already set the DataSource / populated the DataGridView before you put the Binding code, if the DataSource is not set and therefore containing the field that you wish to bind to you will get an error.