# c# textbox databinding update

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, refresh

I have a form that have a datagridview & textbox binding to a datatable(dt)
When press the button, datagridview, textbox can normally update the value

but when I Input a value to Column1
It only update column2's value
textbox can't update

How do I fixed this problem??

Here's my screen & coding

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKbTe.png)

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TESTING
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Field3", typeof(string));

            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "Field1";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].DataPropertyName = "Field2";

            textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Field3");

            dt.Rows.Add();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "Column1":
                    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                    if (dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Field1"].ToString().Trim() == "123")
                    {
                        dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Field2"] = "123-Column2";
                        dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Field3"] = "123-Column3";

                        this.Refresh();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
        {
            int icolumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (icolumn < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn + 1, irow];
                else
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow];

                return true;
            }
            else
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Rows[0]["Field1"] = "123";
            dt.Rows[0]["Field2"] = "123-Column2";
            dt.Rows[0]["Field3"] = "123-Column3";
        }
    }
}
```

`

I tried to rebinding textbox before "this.Refresh()"
but it seems so dumb.....

Comment: It appears your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/8895946/3783776. Based on the second, more recent answer, I would suggest trying `textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt.DataSource, "Field3");`.

Comment: the issue is that the TextBox's data binding for "Field3" is not automatically updating to reflect these changes in the DataTable.

Comment: To make the TextBox update its content when "Field3" changes in the DataTable, you need to use a BindingSource..

Comment: @YasinARLI Thanks for your advice
 I can update the textbox's data now by using ResetBindings(true)

Comment: @YasinARLI I found another way to fixed my problem. Add `dt.Row[e.RowIndex].EndEdit();` before `this.Refresh()`. It's works!